# Migrate Asp .Net v4 to dotnet core 5 got error about

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I got a task to migrate from Asp.net v4 to dotnet core

this is the code that I need to migrate

```cs
 public class DashletConfig : Dictionary<string, dynamic>
    {
        public DashletConfig();

        public T Get<T>(string key, T defaultValue);
        public T Get<T>(string key);
        public T GetObject<T>(string key);
        public T GetObject<T>(string key, T defaultValue);
        public void SetObject(string key, object obj);
    }
```

when I create new class and place this code, I got errors, like this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0501  'DashletConfig.DashletConfig()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial   eValuate.Model


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0501  'DashletConfig.Get<T>(string, T)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial eValuate.Model
```

all the `DashletConfig.Get` are error, I just place one of error.

please help me how to fix this error?

Comment: That wouldn't have compiled in .Net Framework 4 either. A constructor / method must always have a body.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is quite straightforward, you can't have a constructor without declaring a body for it.

I'm guessing you don't want to have any parameters in the constructor, so you can just have:

```
public DashletConfig(){}
```

also, as Jonathan Barclay pointed out, you'd also need to account for your methods too.

for example:

```
    public T Get<T>(string key, T defaultValue){
    enter code here
}
```

Comment: What about the methods too?

Comment: Including the methods too!
thank you for pointing out my mistake there!